# I couldn't find the debug console in Android Studio?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, debugging

[image]

I'm writing a flutter project right now, console output is needed for controls, but I couldn't open the debug console.

I need to control textfields in application. If it is wrong, I need to print output to the console, but I cannot open the console.

[image]

Comment: You might be looking for `debugPrint(YourContrller.text)` or you can add breakPoints. You can follow https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/debugging

Comment: I added a new picture to the question, can you see? it says there but I couldn't find the "run" icon and I couldn't do the others

Comment: Did you tap on debug key?

Comment: where is the debug key ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run the application from the main.dart, above the void main() there will be a run button, click that. That fixed the problem for me.